# Why can't Chromium find a Crosswalk resource, causing an exception in my Android app?

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk

My Android app using Crosswalk and Cordova is causing an exception during long-press events, caused by `onCreateActionMode` in the Crosswalk bundled version of Chromium not finding a value for `R.string.actionbar_textselection_title`.

In order to create a long-press context menu, Chromium is looking up the string associated with R.string.actionbar_textselection_title, which at that point is set to 0, which  defined, and we get this exception on long-press:

```
W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
W/System.err: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
W/System.err:     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:1137)
W/System.err:     at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:1231)
W/System.err:     at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:363)
W/System.err:     at org.chromium.content.browser.WebActionModeCallback.onCreateActionMode(WebActionModeCallback.java:138)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:2694)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionModeForChild(PhoneWindow.java:2619)
W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:675)
W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:675)
W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:675)
W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:675)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.startActionMode(View.java:4738)
W/System.err:     at org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore.startDefaultActionMode(ContentViewCore.java:2167)
W/System.err:     at org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore.startActionMode(ContentViewCore.java:2163)
W/System.err:     at org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore.showSelectActionMode(ContentViewCore.java:2133)
W/System.err:     at org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore.onSelectionEvent(ContentViewCore.java:2239)
W/System.err:     at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:39)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
A/chromium: [FATAL:jni_android.cc(233)] Check failed: false. Please include Java exception stack in crash report
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00006c77 (code=-6), thread 27767
```

This is where the getString is done, in [org/chromium/content/browser/WebActionModeCallback.java](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/chromium-crosswalk/blob/crosswalk-20/50.0.2661.102/content/public/android/java/src/org/chromium/content/browser/WebActionModeCallback.java):

```
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    mode.setTitle(DeviceFormFactor.isTablet(getContext())
                    ? getContext().getString(R.string.actionbar_textselection_title)
                    : null);
    mode.setSubtitle(null);
    mEditable = mActionHandler.isSelectionEditable();
    mIsPasswordType = mActionHandler.isSelectionPassword();
    mIsInsertion = mActionHandler.isInsertion();
    createActionMenu(mode, menu);
    return true;
}
```

During startup my app sometimes (not always) has these errors:

```
W/XWalkInternalResources: org.xwalk.core.R$styleableis not found.
W/XWalkInternalResources: org.xwalk.core.R$styleis not found.
W/XWalkInternalResources: org.xwalk.core.R$stringis not found.
W/XWalkInternalResources: org.xwalk.core.R$rawis not found.
W/XWalkInternalResources: org.xwalk.core.R$menuis not found.
W/XWalkInternalResources: org.xwalk.core.R$layoutis not found.
W/XWalkInternalResources: org.xwalk.core.R$idis not found.
W/XWalkInternalResources: org.xwalk.core.R$drawableis not found.
W/XWalkInternalResources: org.xwalk.core.R$dimenis not found.
W/XWalkInternalResources: org.xwalk.core.R$coloris not found.
W/XWalkInternalResources: org.xwalk.core.R$attris not found.
```

**The main question is:** why does R.string.actionbar_textselection_title not have a value? The string is defined in res/values/android_content_strings.xml:

```
<string name="actionbar_textselection_title">"Text selection"</string>
```

In my onCreate, this resource is available, so it's clearly being loaded:

```
getResources().getText(R.string.actionbar_textselection_title)
Log.d("FOO", (String) foo);

D/FOO: Text selection
```

Is this exception related to the context in which Chromium is trying to access the resource? Is there a remedy for this?

**Pertinent information:** Using Android API 22, build tools 23.0.3, embedding xwalk_core_library_java.jar 20.50.533.12 build as a dependency in Gradle, libxwalkcore.so under jniLibs for ARM and X86 devices, Crosswalk plugin files for Cordova in src/org/crosswalk/engine.

I have a sprawling app that grew organically over several years, containing a lot of code I can't share, so I can only supply bite-sized portions of code and config files.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @eyuelt No resolution yet, I still have the same problem with anything using Chromium assets. All the discussions around this I've been able to find either refer to older bugs that have been fixed, or say that this is normal and not to worry about it. Sadly, when I tell my users that, they turn out to be quite unreasonable about fatal exceptions.

In Chromium's ResourceRewriter.java, this line appears to never get called:
    org.chromium.content.R.onResourcesLoaded(packageId);

From what I've been able to see, if this is called the resources should be properly defined.